# Custom ViewGroup creates two nodes in View Hierarchy

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view that uses a layout to inflate the subviews inside of it.

When this view is created and inflated, the view hierarchy has two plus n views:

`MyCustomView -> RelativeLayout -> {subview1, subview2,…}`

Is there any way to eliminate the RelativeLayout node?

Related class:

```
class MyCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

   ...

   public void start(Context context) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_custom, this);
   }

   ...

}
```

Related XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#232323">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_video"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_slim"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/video_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_largest"
        android:textColor="@color/text_login_gray"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="#232323" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_title"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/video_desc"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/text_very_light_gray"
        android:background="#232323" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How do you fix the funky look in Android Studio's preview when I replace a RelativeLayout with 'merge' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with the merge tag.

This has the added benefit of removing non-sense attributes on the root node.

In some circumstances, this will create visual errors in "Preview".
At this time I am unaware of any fix for that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_video"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_slim"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/video_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_largest"
        android:textColor="@color/text_login_gray"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:background="#232323" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_title"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_medium"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/video_desc"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
        android:textColor="@color/text_very_light_gray"
        android:background="#232323" />

</merge>
```